# How do I add this row and column data to a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to read a file which has say

```
Name,Date,Place

Tom,1/1/2010,America
Dick,2/2/2011,China
Harry,3/3/2012,Germany
```

And adds the column headers to a String and the values to an ArrayList.

```
HashMap<String columnName ,ArrayList<String> Value>
```

So the program should run like,

```
if(lineNumber == 1)
{
   interate through values and create headers
}
else
   add values to corresponding header list
```

My problem is I do not know how I can reference the arraylist in the `else` part of the code.
If anybody has done something similar I would like to hear from you !

**Edit**

So I have something like this so far,

```
public void consumeLine(String path,int lineNumber,List line){

    if(lineNumber == 1)
    {
        ListIterator listIterator = line.listIterator();
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
        {   
            hashMap.put(listIterator.next().toString(),new ArrayList<String>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: if only first line is header then it would do, or better would be to have some identifier (logical) to identify the header

Comment: @Tom celic is the first line always the header?

Comment: @Tomcelic if the header is always first... why so `lineNumber == 1`?

Comment: Are the values always separated by spaces? What would you want to happen for a line like: `John Smith 01/01/2010 America`?

Comment: Is this **homework**? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: no it isn't **homework**, also @Baqueta it is a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create an ordered list of the column names, and iterate through that as you iterate through the values in each row.

Something like this (untested code!):

```
ListIterator listIterator = line.listIterator();
if(lineNumber == 1)
{
    while(listIterator.hasNext())
    {   
        String key = listIterator.next().toString();
        keyList.add(key); // keyList is a List<String> instance field.
        hashMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
} else {
    Iterator<String> keyIterator = keyList.iterator();
    while(keyList.hasNext() && listIterator.hasNext())
    {
        String key = keyList.next();
        String value = listIterator.next();
        ArrayList<String> values = hashMap.get(key);
        values.add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        int lineNumber = 1;
        String[] columnName = null;
        ArrayList<String[]> value = new ArrayList<String[]>(); // temp array
        String line;
        String[] arr;
        while (reader.ready())
            if (!(line = reader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
                arr = line.split("\\s+");
                if (lineNumber == 1)
                    columnName = arr;// create headers
                else
                    value.add(arr);// create values
                lineNumber++;
            }
        // transform data
        for (int i = 0; i < columnName.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < value.size(); j++)
                ar.add(value.get(j)[i]);
            map.put(columnName[i], ar);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
```